# How do you autonumber videos in playlists downloaded from youtube with Jdownloader 2

Tags: video, youtube, jdownloader

I have a large number of lectures and videos from playlists that only make sense if you play them in order and I can't number each of a 1000 10 minute videos. How can I prepend the  number in jdownloader to the name as in {int}-{name}. Is there another youtube downloader that has this setting built in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JDownloader 2, go to Settings -> Plugins and then select the *Youtube* plugin.

Go to the bottom of the page and customize the filenames adding the video number as prefix

e.g: `*VIDEONUMBER[000]*-*VIDEO_NAME*.*EXT*`

Screenshot:

[image: here]

For your purpose, You may find useful to customize the other fields as well... I use to add the *playlist_id* in the "customized packagename" to facilitate my organization later.

Answer (score -1):

While JDownloader 2 may or may not have the ability, [4k video downloader](https://www.4kdownload.com/products/product-videodownloader) has the option under Tools>preferences>Add the numeration to the file names in playlists.